# Node exiting when run under windows task scheduler without error and doesn't await promise/callback

Tags: node.js, windows, async-await

My main observations are:

1. If an async function is run inside a forEach loop like: `await Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key) { an_async_func() }`

Then it fails to run.

2. Hwoever, when I change the same code to: `for (var key in o) {  an_async_func()  }`

Then it does run.

Outside of task scheduler, like from a windows CLI both cases will run the async function fine.

I have attempted a minimal viable example but it does not manifest the same problem (the example I drafted is below for what it is worth).

```
'use strict'

const timeoutPromise = (time) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(() =>
        { console.log('timeout=',time); resolve('done') }, time) })
}

async function main() {
  var o = { a:1,b:2 }

  await Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key) {
     timeoutPromise(5000)
     console.log(key)
  })
}

main()
```

So I'm still scratching my head as to what the issue was.

Comment: You're wrong that the code runs just fine in the CLI.  It may run, but the loop does not run serially at all.  The loop just runs to completion and the `await` does nothing and then sometime later all your timers fire.  So, it runs, but it doesn't do what you intend in any environment.  This code is just wrongly implemented in several ways.

Comment: In what way is it wrong? If the object is to have the async functions run, would it be wrong in that sense? Yes, you are right the `await` probably does nothing. But I just need the async functions to actually run within task scheduler

Comment: What's the real code doing that's asynchronous?  I presume you're not just running timers and logging them.  Can we please see the real code so we can work on a real solution rather than a solution to your pseudo-code.  If all you want to do is run some promise-returning function in sequence in a loop, the hoangdv answer already shows that.  Don't know what else you want help with.  Actual code please with your real problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sure, please find here actual code: https://github.com/pbvillaflores/airmessage

Comment: That's a bunch of code and I have no idea what I'm looking for in that.  You would need to tell us what debugging you've done, which lines of code run fine when run from the scheduler and exactly where the problem starts to occur, what errors are occuring, etc...  You will probably have to log to a persistent file to diagnose this.  When I've run stuff in the task scheduler, I've had issues with the current directory and making sure file paths were correct since the task scheduler doesn't set that the same as running the program manually, but I have no idea if that's your issue or not.

Comment: So far, you haven't shown us any evidence that what you have posted in your question is where the issue is in your real code.  Do you have any real evidence of that or is that just a guess?

Comment: FYI, I also see missing error handling in your code.  For example, the `csvPromise` function ignores all errors.  Same with `Promise.all(all_send_results)` which has no `.catch()`.  Go find EVERY place you're not catching and logging errors and start logging them and log them in a way you can see them when run from task scheduler.  I'm betting you will learn a bunch.  There appear to be dozens of places you're ignoring errors.

Comment: Also, the `all_send_results.push(timeoutPromise(1000));` seems pointless.  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that.

Comment: The timeoutPromise() was added only because I was testing and trying to work out what the problem was. Thanks for the point about the .catch(). I have added that a while back now and didn't get any errors coming through so far. It's still a mystery why the code performs differently and doesn't run async functions to completion when running from task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

`await Object.keys(o).forEach` doesn't work,  because  `.forEach` does not return a `Promise`, it return a `void`. `await` just work with a Promise (or `thenable` object).

In this case, just use a `for loop` without callback (`.forEach(callback)`) as `for in`, and you need `await` a async task (if you want to wait until the task finish)

```
'use strict'

const timeoutPromise = (time) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timeout=', time);
      resolve('done');
    }, time)
  })
}

async function main() {
  var o = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  }

  for (const key in o) {
    await timeoutPromise(5000); // sleep
    console.log(key)
  }
}

main()
```

Comment: I understand a promise or an async function does not need to be returned in order for it to be completed. The other strange thing is that it works fine if run interactively. It only acts up when run from Task Scheduler